# Time-derivative of an operator

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-algebras

Would I be right in thinking that the operator $$\hat O'(t)$$ is different from the operator $$D\hat O(t)$$ where $D={d\over dt}$, since when acting on a function $f$, the second corresponds to $$\hat O'(t)f+\hat O(t){d\over dt}f$$?

---

Suppose $\hat O(t)$ is an operator acting on a space of functions $f=f(x,t)$.

I wish to find an antisymmetric operator $\hat P$ such that $$\hat O'(t)=P\hat O$$. As commented above, I don't think $P={d\over dt}$ would work. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear to me that is the derivative of an operator. I don't know if there is a standard definition, what is the definition in your context?